# Docker compose, NGINX not serving static files

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, docker-compose

I am trying to serve a simple `Flask` app over with `NGINX` using `Docker Compose`. But NGINX will not serve my static files.

I am using an `Ubuntu 18.04` box. Here is my file structure:

```
    .
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    ├── nginx
    │   └── sites-enabled
    │       └── nginx.conf
    ├── README.md
    ├── uwsgi.ini
    └── web
        ├── app
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── static
        │   │   ├── pics
        │   │   │   ├── headshot1.jpg
        │   │   │   └── headshot2.jpg
        │   │   ├── scripts.js
        │   │   └── styles.css
        │   └── templates
        │       ├── index.html
        │       └── layout.html
        └── run.py
```

Here is my `nginx.conf`:

```
    http {
      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location /static {
          alias /usr/src/app/app/static;
        }

        location / {
          include uwsgi_params;
          uwsgi_pass web:5000;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
      }
    }
```

And my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2"

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    expose:
      - "5000"
    volumes:
      - ./web:/usr/src/app
    command: >
      bash -c "uwsgi --socket :5000 \
                     --chdir /usr/src/app \
                     --wsgi-file run.py \
                     --callable app \
                     --master \
                     --processes 4 \
                     --threads 2"

  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:1.15
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /www/static
      - ./nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    volumes_from:
      - web
    links:
      - web:web
```

When I run the containers, I can access my site from the internet, but none of the static files (CSS, images) are served. When I go into the NGINX container, I can find the static files:

```
$ docker exec -it my_container_1_39dbd8b7e8dc ls -l /usr/src/app/app/static/pics
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  8 18:39 pics
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb  8 18:39 scripts.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3793 Feb  8 18:39 styles.css
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Maybe it's a file permission issue?

**EDIT:** adding references to `static/` directory:

**`HTML`:**

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css"/>`

**`CSS`:**

```
#right {
  float: right;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,55,164, 0.75), rgba(0, 55, 164, 0.9)),
    url(pics/headshot1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: Serve /use/src/? But didn't you just put all the files into /web/app/?

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is with how you are including static files in your html. Could you show us that?

Comment: @nebuler I added references to how I am calling the static files.

Comment: Ok that looks good. Another question: are you writing nginx.conf from scratch? If so, I don't see you including `mime.types` in it. Try adding a line `include mime.types;` under http block.

Comment: looks like the `mime.types` was the issue. thanks!